# How to show external sqlite database's data in customize listview in android studio?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, oop

I would like to know is this the way to show data at customize listview in android studio using/ oop & sqlite?

In this java page, I assigned them here

```
public static Model txn;

    public static SQLiteHelper mSQLiteHelper;
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayList<Model> mList;
    RecordListAdapter mAdapter = null;
```

After that, I initialized them

```
mListView =findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new RecordListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and here is the code that i tried to grab them all and show out. And I met a problem at this line `mList.add(new Model(id, name, address, phone));`.

```
try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("Table1", new String[]{"id", "name", "address", "phone"}, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
            mList.clear();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                int id = cursor.getInt(3);
                String name = cursor.getString(0);
                String address = cursor.getString(1);
                String phone = cursor.getString(2);

                mList.add(new Model(id, name, address, phone));
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (mList.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No record found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here is the red error says

```
Model() in Model cannot be applied to:
Expected Actual
Parameters: Arguments

id(int)
name(java.lang.String)
address(java.lang.String)
phone(java.lang.String)
```

Here is my model page

```
public class Model {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

what can I do to fix this? thanks in advance...

Comment: Hello Leon. Could you share your Model class?

Comment: Hi. I've edited my Model. Please do check it. thanks @JuanjoBerenguer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing to create the constructor:

**Model**

```
public class Model {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;

    public Model(int id,String name,String address,String phone){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.phone = phone;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

I think this should solve that error.

Comment: It fixed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a constructor that takes the 4 parameters. You need something like :-

```
   public Model(int id,String name,String address,String phone){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.phone = phone;
    }
```

in your Model class.

Additionally use :-

```
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String address = cursor.getString(2);
            String phone = cursor.getString(3);
```

i.e. offset 0 is the first column in the cursor i.e. **id**,  **3** is **phone**.

Although better to get offsets according to the column name. e.g. (and ideally use Constants for table and column names, rather than hard code them everywhere).

```
            int id = cursor.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("id"));
```

If this doesn't fix the issue then edit your question to include the stack-trace.

Comment: problem is here. `mList.add(new Model(id, name, address, phone));` It says Model() in Model cannot be applied to:
Expected Actual
Parameters: Arguments

id(int)
name(java.lang.String)
address(java.lang.String)
phone(java.lang.String)